# map a matrix content from another matrix R which has not the same length

Tags: r, dictionary, matrix, datatable, mapping

I have a matrix extracted with R which has many NA values ( values not found in the text for extraction)

And i have a reference csv file that contain all combination possibilities of the same data

this is a part of my matrix

data matrix;

```
       OMIM   GENES_SYMBOL         GENES        CHROMOSOME
1      (NA)       (arlts1)    (perforin)              (NA)
2      (NA)          (mtr)          (NA)              (NA)
3    (325410)         (NA)          (NA)              (NA)
4      (NA)         (t341c)          (NA)              (5)
```

this is how the csv matrix looks like

dictionary matrix;

```
  OMIM      GENES_SYMBOL     GENES                               CHROMOSOME
 "612367"   "alpqtl2"  anorexia nervosa,a 1"                        1
 "606788"   "arlts1"    basal cell carcinoma, susceptibility to,      3
 "325410"   "bcc1"     bone mineral density qtl 3                    10
```

I want to map the first matrix with the second one to fill all equivalent values and get rid of `NA`. the problem is the matrices have not the same length`( the second >>>>> the first)` and rows in both are not organised the same; *the 1st row of the `data matrix` can be the row number 500 in the `dictionary matrix`*

I wrote this code but it worked only when 2 matrices have same length. If not it returns only 2 columns from the `data matrix`

```
genemap<- data.table::fread("GeneMap - Copy.csv",sep="\t")

fun <- function(rowi,genemap) {
  res <- apply(as.data.frame(genemap),1,function(x) {length(na.omit(match(na.omit(rowi),x)))})
  IND <- which(  max(datamatrix) == datamatrixs  )[1]

  rowi[is.na(rowi)] <- unlist(genemap[IND,])[is.na(rowi)]
  return(rowi)
}

as.data.frame(t(apply(datamatrix, 1, fun, genemap))
)
        OMIM   GENES_SYMBOL       
1      (NA)       (arlts1)   
2      (NA)          (mtr)         
3    (325410)         (NA)         
4      (NA)        ( t341c)
```

any suggestion to modify the code??

Comment: Are you sure these are matrices? They look like dataframes to me. R only allows one data type in matrices (i.e., all numeric data), while dataframes can have multiple data types (numeric, character, etc. like your data)

Comment: I extrated numbers as text character.. If the solution is applicable with dataframe I can convert them there is no problem with data type I need the content @JanBoyer

Comment: You can identify the class of your objects using `class()`. Regarding your code, there are a number of things that are not clear, like what is object `rowi`, also you use `datamatrix` and `datamatrixs` within your function `fun` without defining them. You should have a look at [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right#1300618) on how to join two dataframes. You could either join on each column (omim, genename, genesymbol) seperately and then combine the results, or construct a more complex sql query using the `sqldf` package.